# Is it possible to compress images with Imagine library?

Tags: php, image

I use [Imagine library](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) and I would like to know if is it possible to compress images with this library?

Other question:

- Do you think it's a good solution to compress a lot (30 images) of images with the library in order to use a command line?

Answer (score -1):

You can save the images with lesser quality to compress them:

To save at 50% quality:

```
$imagine->open('/path/to/image.jpg')->save('/path/to/image.jpg', array('quality' => 50));
```

And as for whether or not to do the compression at command line, you can do it but I don't recommend it. Image manipulation takes a lot of cpu and ram, so I suggest you download the images and manipulate them on your computer (not on the production server), or do it in a php script but limit the number of images to compress.